# Bootstrap toggle-switch hyperlink layout issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use bootstrap [toggle-switch](http://bootstrap.snipplicious.com/snippet/27/toggle-switch) to allow my website users to switch languages. The issue is that when I put a link for each bottom, they now look like 2 separate buttons and no longer like the original toggle-switch. What is the issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/ctap672a/2/

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle float-right">
  <button class="btn btn-default">FRANCAIS</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary active">ENGLISH</button>
</div>
```

With links:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle float-right">
  <a href="index-fr.html"><button class="btn btn-default">FRANCAIS</button></a>
  <a href="index-en.html"><button class="btn btn-primary active">ENGLISH</button></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your html to use only the anchor tag with the button classes like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle float-right">
  <a href="index-fr.html" class="btn btn-default">FRANCAIS</a>
  <a href="index-en.html" class="btn btn-primary active">ENGLISH</a>
</div>
```